# Variable is not set after subscribe method

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm having event on my input after focus is lost on input I'm trying to get data from API, data is get correct but after second focus on input, after first nothing is setting.

my service

```
public getContractorByNIP(NIP: string) {
    let httpParam = new HttpParams().set('NIP', NIP);
    return this.httpClient.get<GpContractor>('http://localhost:8080/InvoiceAPI/invoice/contractor', {params: httpParam});
  }
```

my component

```
onFocusLost() {
    if (this.contractorNIP.valid){
      this.getContractorByNIP(this.contractorNIP.value.toString());
    }
  }

  getContractorByNIP(NIP: string) {
      this.contractorService.getContractorByNIP(NIP)
        .subscribe((data) => this.contractor = data);
  }
```

my html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="NIP kontrahenta" formControlName="gpContractorNIP" class="matIn" (focusout)="onFocusLost()" minlength="10" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}$">
 </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I expect to set data in first time after focus is lost.

Comment: Share your html

Comment: html is updated

Comment: What do you want, to display data in input? or to call to server API method only at first time?

Comment: I want to call API server and fill form but after first time when I lose focus form is not filled after second time all working as expected

Answer (score 0):

this.contractorNIP.value.toString() should be this.gpContractorNIP.value.toString()

Also you have used formControl so you will need to get value of model by subscribing to valueOnChanges on this.gpContractorNIP.